# How to get the inner measure of the Vitali set.

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

I know that this should be very easy, but why exactly is the inner measure of the Vitali set 0?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that for any collection of disjoint sets $\{U_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{Z}}$, we have
$$
\mu_*(\bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} U_n) \geq \sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}}\mu_*(U_n)
$$
Now, if we take $U_n$ to be a covering of $[0,1]$ under the usual construction, we find that $\mu_*(U_n)$ is the same for each $n$.  Let $M$ be this value, then
$$
\mu_*(\bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} U_n) \geq \sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}}\mu_*(U_n)
= \sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}} M
$$
This can only be true if $M = 0$.

Comment: Inner measure is translation invariant, that is used here. Is inner measure translation invariant?

Comment: @Arindam inner measure is indeed translation invariant.

Comment: I do not see it, can you give some hints

Comment: @Arindam I think you should post your own question.

Comment: I have posted the question.http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2123251/lebesgue-inner-measure-is-translation-invariant