# $E\subseteq \mathbb{R}$ and $m^*(E)<\infty$: $E$ is measurable iff $m^*(E)=m^*(A)+m^*(E-A)$ for any $A \subseteq E$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory

Suppose $E\subseteq \mathbb{R}$ and $m^*(E)<\infty$. Prove that $E$ is measurable if and only if for any subset $A \subseteq E$, we have: $$m^*(E)=m^*(A)+m^*(E-A)$$

If $E$ is measurable and $A$ is any subset of $E$ (not necessarily measurable), since $E=A \cup (E-A)$ and $A\cap (E-A) = \emptyset$ we have:
$m^*(E) =  m^*(A) + m^*(E-A)$
(a proof can be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/469027/for-an-outer-measure-m-does-me-cup-ame-cap-a-mema-alw?lq=1))

For the other direction, I think one possible strategy is to prove that the additivity property for two disjoint sets still holds and then use it to prove $m^*(X)=m^*(X\cap E)+m^*(X \cap E^c)$ for any $X \subseteq \mathbb{R}$. However, I haven't succeeded yet.

Comment: If $E$ is measurable and $A$ is ANY subset of $E$, then $A$ and $E-A$ may be non-measurable sets, and
then you cannot use the result presented in http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/469027/for-an-outer-measure-m-does-me-cup-ame-cap-a-mema-alw?lq=1
 
In fact, it may not be true that $m^*(E) =  m^*(A) + m^*(E-A)$.

Comment: @Ramiro: Read the statement of the problem in that question again. It proves it for any $A$ and nowhere in the proof given by martini measurability of $A$ has been assumed.

Comment: @H.Z. In the problem in that question (http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/469027/for-an-outer-measure-m-does-me-cup-ame-cap-a-mema-alw?lq=1 )  we have two sets, namely $A$ and $E$, and one of them is measurable (namely $E$) then we can conclude that 
$$m^*(E\cup A)+m^*(E\cap A) = m^*(E)+m^*(A)$$
Here you are incorrectly applying  that result to $A$ and $E-A$, where both may be non-measurable.

Comment: @H.Z. You seem to be confusing your $E$ here with the $E$ there. But to use the result in that question, the way you did,  it is your $E-A$ (which may be non-measurable) that would play the role of $E$  there.

Comment: @Ramiro OK. Now I understand it. Thanks.

Comment: @H.Z. Here is an example where $E\subseteq \mathbb{R}$ is **measurable**, $m^*(E)<\infty$ and there is a subset $A \subseteq E$, such that $$m^*(E)<m^*(A)+m^*(E-A)$$
Take $E=[0,1]$ and $A$ to be a Vitali set  of outer measure 1 (they exist, see http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/157532/vitali-set-of-outer-measure-exactly-1?rq=1 ). Since $A$ is not Lebesgue measurable, $[0,1]-A$ is not Lebesgue measurable and so $m^*([0,1]-A)>0$. So we have $$m^*([0,1])=1<1+m^*([0,1]-A)=m^*(A)+m^*([0,1]-A)$$

Comment: @H.Z. Here is a simpler example where $E\subseteq \mathbb{R}$ is **measurable**, $m^*(E)<\infty$ and there is a subset $A\subseteq E$ such that 
$$ m^*(E)<m^*(A)+m^*(E-A)$$
Take $E=[0,1]$ and $A$ be a Vitali set. Since $A$ is not Lebesgue measurable, we have that $m^*(A)>0$. On the other hand, we know that the inner measure of $A$ is zero, that is $m_*(A)=0$ (see, for inatance, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/739089/how-to-get-the-inner-measure-of-the-vitali-set ), and so we have $m^*([0,1]-A)=1$. Then 
$$m^*([0,1])=1<1 +m^*(A) = m^*(A) + m^*([0,1]-A)$$